# Sublime Text Editor: searching for files path

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I navigate files in Sublime Text Editor I use `Ctrl+p` to have it look for file names. Is there a similar function that lets me also use parts of the path as search parameter?

Ex: say I have two files with same name in `/views` and `/controllers`: how to return only the result in the controller folder when looking for something like `filename controllers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already do this with `ctrl+P`, just use `/` to indicate that the previous part was a directory name:

**WITHOUT specific directory**

[image: WITHOUT specific directory]

---

**WITH specific directory**

[image: WITH specific directory]